# How do you add repeating images in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

In my Phaser game, I want to use a cell-like background texture which moves when you move.

My idea was to add each cell in a for loop like this:

```js
  let width=100, height=100;
  for(let y=0;y<width;y++){
    ;
    for(let x=0; x<height;x++){
    
      this.physics.add.image(width/2+64*x, height/2+64*y, "snow_field").setScale(4,4);
      
    }
  }
```

The problem: The game gets very (**very**) slow

So is there a better / recommended way to add repeating images/backgrounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `Phaser.GameObjects.TileSprite` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.TileSprite.html))

> ...
> *A TileSprite is a Sprite that has a repeating texture.*
> ...

```
this.add.tileSprite(posX, posY, width, height, "snow_field");
```

here is a small [official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/container/add-tilesprite-to-container), where you can see it in action.